# How to change the number of posts that Wordpress JSON Api loads per page

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

How to change the number of posts that WordPress JSON API loads per page.

The default is 25, because of low internet connection I want to make it less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [in the documentation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#2.1.-Core-controller-methods), you can specify the maximum number of posts in the response with the `count` parameter in your request.

Example with user-friendly permalinks configured:

```
http://www.example.org/api/get_posts/?count=10
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are on newer WordPress version then acording to their docs

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments

**`per_page`** argument is used now.. like

```
https://www.example.org/api/get_posts/?per_page=100
```